# AWS QuickSight custom SQL query on Athena

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-athena, amazon-quicksight

I have a pipeline where AWS Kinesis Firehose receives data, converts it to parquet-format based on an Athena table and stores it in an S3 bucket based on a date-partition (date_int: YYYYMMdd). Whenever new data is added to the bucket, a lambda is triggered to check if Athena already knows about the partition. Everything seems to be working fine; in Athena I can run a query (see below) and the newest data is received.

Athena query: `SELECT * FROM "my_table" WHERE "date_int" >= 20210308`
(On the left-hand side of the screen the correct Data Source and Database are selected)

Now I want to visualise the data in Quicksight. I can use either SPICE or direct query, again, all seems to be working fine. However, I have the data partitioned, because I only need datapoints of, say, the last month. In Quicksight I create a new dataset, choose the correct catalog/database/table and click 'Use custom SQL'. Then, when I run the query, I always get an error from the Athena client saying the table couldn't be find. When I look in the network tab, I see the query performed being:
`/* QuickSight */SELECT ds.* FROM ( SELECT * FROM "my_table" ) ds LIMIT 0`
Then the error message saying:
`Table awsdatacatalog.default.my_table does not exist`

The strange part is, I didn't say it should be looking at the 'default' database. I select 'awsdatacatalog' as the datasource and 'my_database' as the database. When I try to be more precise and specify the datasource and database in the select statement ("awsdatacatalog.my_database.my_table"), the error message will say "awsdatacatalog.default.awsdatacatalog.my_database.my_table".

Anyone else having the same problem? Is this a bug, or am I just missing something?

Comment: Can you try by try by selecting Override client-side settings for your workgroup in  https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/workgroups-settings-override.html

Comment: Thanks for your reply! It didn't fix it unfortunately, still the same error.

Comment: Try to SELECT *  FROM database_name.table_name. Without catalog.

Comment: Unfortunately, doesn't work either. It will always prepend the 'awsdatacatalog.default'. For now, I worked around most of it by aggregating using athena and reading separate tables in quicksight.

Answer (score 4):

It worked for me by using datasource.database_name.table_name.
Try using SELECT * FROM awsdatacatalog.my_database.my_table